# Android - RuntimeException due to a Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, crash, resources, filenotfoundexception, runtimeexception

Morning everybody,
I have a weird problem with a production app. Some users get a RuntimeException apparently due to a ResourceNotFoundException. I got the crash via Sentry but cannot reproduce it on any of my devices. The error seems to be on the splash.xml that can not be found, but this file is located in the drawable folder. Am I missing something here?

This Error is not specific to an Android version, I got it from version 5 to 9 of Android, same for the brands, it happened on Samsung, Lenovo, etc...

Here is the splash.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/content_background" />

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_welcome" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

And the splash_welcome is a png defined in the different drawable density folders :
[splash_welcome declarations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6pOH.png)

Here is a part of my manifest where I define the theme that contains the drawable :

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Splash">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Here is the Theme declaration (styles.xml in the values folder):

```
<style name="AppTheme.Splash" parent="AppTheme.Transparent">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
</style>
```

Here is the stack trace :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.InputStream.close()' on a null object reference
    at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateSpr(DrawableInflater.java:239)
    at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:127)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1251)
    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:287)
    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:196)
    at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:134)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1251)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1224)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:765)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:621)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1640)
    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
    at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:463)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:203)
    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:86)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:260)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2877)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/splash.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070092
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:775)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:621)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1640)
    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
    at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:463)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:203)
    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:86)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:260)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2877)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.***.myapp/de.***.myapp.SplashActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable de.***.myapp:drawable/splash with resource ID #0x7f070092
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2924)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please post the flash.xml here so we can see what's inside. Is it a vector drawable? Is it a layer-list? what android versions give you the exceptions?

Comment: Is this xml in drawable or any other drawable folder?

Comment: You have two exception here, null pointer and resource not found exception. Post your splash.xml file here.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I added the info you asked to the post.

Comment: @Bali it's in the drawable folder

Comment: @KaushikBurkule I added it to the post

Comment: Can you also add the part of your code where you add those drawables to your views? Are you doing it programmatically or in the xml?

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I updated the post again to show where it's set. It comes from a theme property, the theme is set in the manifest as I showed.

Comment: When you use split APK or bundle then only drawables from density of the device are downloaded. In other words if you have "splash_welcome_tonie" only in drawable-hdpi and drawable-xhdpi then it'll crash on device with device density mdpi, xxhdpi etc... This is usually the cause of this issue. Here i can't say much since i don't know if you're using the constraints i mentioned. Anyway do check.

Comment: @Bali I am not sure of it, I have to ask because I just landed in this project and I never built it. However, if it would be the case, what would be the solution? Put the drawable on every density folder or add a default one in the drawable folder?

Comment: yes(either in all density folders or drawable) bith works BTW if you can see the device info on which crash occurring then you can google their screen density.

Comment: @Bali your guess was right we use a Bundle (.aab)

Comment: @Bali thanks for the tip I will check it !

Comment: @Bali The fact is that I checked 5 of the devices that represent more than 50% of the crashes and they seem to have around 400-500 PPI which should correspond to xxhdpi. But the png is already defined in the xxhdpi resource folder. Does it mean that I should replicate my splash.xml in every density? It's weird...

Comment: Also error point on the splash.xml (even though it could be a consequence of a problem with the inner png splash_welcome_tonie)

Comment: I said splash_welcome_tonie as an example. From your log "splash.xml" is the file not present in the apk causing error. And i just mentioned one of the cause for such error. Try to pinpoint error by checking (whether crash is happening on only one device brand, or Android version etc...) . Best would be if you can find a device with crash so you can fix and test it.

Comment: @Bali as I said, it happens in many brands of phones and Android versions. I found a way to detect incomplete installations and I also disabled the density split in my android bundle config. I will update this ticket if it solves the problem.